# Deleting item out of a List

Tags: dictionary

Does anyone has an idea how I can delete items out of the list (e.g. word a, the)? I am trying several ways, but do not arrive at a solution. Thank you for your help!

```
lst = list() 
for key, val in list(counts.items()):
    lst.append((val, key)) 
    lst.sort(reverse=True) 

for key, val in lst[:10]: 
    print(key, val)
```

Comment: Yes I would like to delete the key/value pair when the key is a or the.

Comment: Please shorten your code to show an example of your dictionary and not all the extra stuff

Comment: That is the short version:

lst = list()
for key, val in list(counts.items()):
    lst.append((val, key))

lst.sort(reverse=True)

for key, val in lst[:10]:
    print(key, val)

253 the
202 and
170 risk
160 to
138 of
122 data
94 a
75 in
74 should
56 be

Comment: I think you are confused between dictionaries and lists. A list is a list of values. A dictionary is a list of keys that correspond to certain values, such as words to their definitions. I believe what you have here is a list, which means you should not be doing `for key, val` but rather just `for val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the definition of `counts` but it looks like a `dict` of words to number of occurrences. If so, then this will do what you want

```
blacklist = ['a', 'the', 'an', 'and']
for key, value in [(k, v) for (k, v) in sorted(counts.iteritems(), reverse=True) if k not in blacklist]:
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
```

The code above doesn't actually remove keys from your counts, it just filters them out of the loop. If you actually need to delete them (since that's what you asked for), use `dict.pop()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop))

```
blacklist = ['a', 'the', 'an', 'and']
for key in blacklist:
    counts.pop(key, None)
```